# PHP - Which class invoked my static method?

Tags: php, methods, static

I need to know what kind invokes a static method, without sending as parameter

```
class foo
{
    public static function test($clase)
    {
        echo "Class invoke:" . FUNCTION();
    }
}

class A { public function x { foo::test(); } }
class B { public function y { foo::test(); } }
class C { public function z { foo::test(); } }
```

Comment: You could use `debug_backtrace()`, but I hope this isn't for production use?

Comment: You could pass `get_class()` as an argument to `test()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use late static bindings and [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/get_called_class) (PHP >= 5.3) if you make all of your classes extend `foo`, like this:

```
class foo
{
    public static function test($clase)
    {
        echo "Class invoke:" . get_called_class();
    }
}

class A extends foo { public function x() { self::test(''); } }
class B extends foo { public function y() { self::test(''); } }
class C extends foo { public function z() { self::test(''); } }
```

With these objects:

```
$a = new A; $a->x();
$b = new B; $b->y();
$c = new C; $c->z();
```

You'll [get as output](http://viper-7.com/4aszOv):

```
Class invoke:A
Class invoke:B
Class invoke:C
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any way without inheritance?

Comment: Not without passing the class name to `test()`.

Comment: @nickb No, there is :). Using `debug_backtrace()`. But again, not a good idea for any sort of production use.

Comment: I'll have to send an object as a parameter, thanks @ nickb, because as Colin Morelli says use debug_backtrace "not a good idea for any sort of production use."

Comment: @Colin - I don't consider `debug_backtrace()` as a viable or valid solution... If you have to suffix a suggestion with "don't use it in production", it's not a viable solution.

Comment: @nickb Sure it is. If this is to be used in a one-time job, or if this only runs in a controlled dev environment. Plenty of things that are completely unacceptable for production use are fine to use in controlled situations. Maybe we'll have to agree to disagree on that. Don't try to tell me you haven't hacked together something just to make it work when it wasn't actually going to be used in production.

Comment: @nickb To follow up on that, considering the OP is echoing the calling method, I had already sort of assumed this wasn't going to be used for production, and hopefully was just being used to track down a bug or something. But would you really consider changing all of the classes to extend `foo` when they don't use any of it's instance methods or properties a viable solution either?